# Google Sheet asking for authorization gets 401: deleted_client

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I cannot seem to get past the Google Authorization pop that always returns Error 401: deleted_client.

I created a Google sheet script a while back and I need to get it working again. I made a GCP account and tried messing around with that for hosting the app but I realized I didn't need that so I deleted all of my projects and my billing account. But I still can't get past the Google Sheet error when it tries to authorize my account. This worked before I started anything with GCP and was fine.

I've seen other issues saying that there needs to have some fixes in the GCP account and that's fine and all but I do not want this connected to GCP at all. I will never use GCP again and I can't even find a way to shut down the account entirely without removing my Google account.

I've tried clearing all cache and cookies from chrome since the beginning of time like some others have suggested that doesn't fix the issue either.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing but, if your script uses Google APIs you *must* associate the script with a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project.

See [Google Cloud Platform projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) for an explanation of this relationship.

GCP projects are used to group enabled Google services, to provide identities and configure OAuth.

Please read the document but see (re)[creating OAuth credentials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#creating_oauth_credentials).

You'll need to:

- Create a GCP project
- Enable Google services
- Configure OAuth consent

Answer (score 0):

DazWilkin lead me in the right direction!
The last thing that was needed was to go to the existing Google Sheet script, hit the gear in the left panel of the new editor, then change the GCP project number to match the GCP project I created with OAuth creds. Thanks again!

Comment: This is not a (welcome where valid) self-answer. One pretty sincere form of thanking for a helpful answer is [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).